# generating a pseudo unique number(code) based on a sequence of numbers with no repetition within 4 digits

Tags: php, math, hash

I'm generating a somewhat unique code that I don't want to repeat within at least 1000 consecutive numbers

this is my function. take a number multiply it by another number then take the last `$length=5` digits before the decimal point

```
function createPseudoUniqueString($input,$length)
{
    return substr( intval($input*738510.93067),-$length) ;
}
```

is there a way to validate that the resulting numbers do not repeat other than testing all the possibilities?

Is there another alternative that is known not to have be repeating

Comment: If you want a code that should not repeat for 1000 consecutive digits, you could just return the last 3 digits (or more) of input, or is that too easy? ;) By the way, I wonder if the PHP tag is appropriate. This seems like a generic question that applies to any programming language, or actually not even programming. It's more a math problem. Have you considered posting on http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: the problem with using the last x digits is that the generated codes do not look random, and become predictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design a custom [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) that generates random 5-digit numbers and is guaranteed not to repeat until it has generated all of them.

An LCG generates random numbers using the following formula:

Xn+1 = ((Xn * a) + c) mod m

To generate 5-digit numbers m should be 100000 (range of 0-99999).

To guarantee no repeats (a "full period") you have to select values for a and c using the following criteria:

> c and m are relatively prime
>
> a - 1 is divisible by all prime factors of m
>
> a - 1 is a multiple of 4 if m is a multiple of 4.

The prime factors of 100000 are 2 and 5, and it's also divisible by 4, so any multiple of 20 + 1 will work as a suitable value of a, being careful not to set it too large to avoid integer overflows. For c just choose a reasonably large prime number.

e.g: m = 100000, a = 4781, c = 62873

Set an initial seed value for x and then generate each value from the previous one using `$x = (($x*4781)+62873)%100000;`

Note that you can't just use a random number generator with a larger period and then mod 100000 the generated values, because even though the raw generated numbers from the larger-period RNG don't repeat, that doesn't guarantee that the numbers mod 100K won't.

Comment: I chose different numbers (so the the first two digits don't look so much like a sequence). I also used `substr ` instead of `%10000` so I wouldn't lose the leading zeros

Comment: @Daniel Don't use `substr` for that. It is actually a questionable "feature" of PHP that you can take a "substring" of a number.  `substr` won't work as expected if `(x*a + c)` is less than `m`. Computing the number and formatting with leading zeros are two independent problems, so use `%10000` for the computation, then `sprintf()` to format the result with leading zeros!